# What is the correct domain with a samba server?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, samba

I have the following: I have a server running linux and samba. I have a Win XP Pro laptop that should access files via samba. The username on the laptop and teh samba server are different. Therefore I have to log in as different user when I want to connect to samba.

This works so far. Now I want to save my username/password on the laptop as I am the only one using it. I found out where to put things (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385095/samba-shared-drive-wont-auto-authenticate-at-startup); I am asked for server, username and password by windows.

For the server I give the IP of the server, right? Or do I need a literal name to look up?

What name have I to give? Win wants a domain within it and I do not know which one I have to give. The samba server does not act as a domain controller. So the question is: What is correct here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For server name you may give its `host name` or `netbios name` or `ip address`.

As your samba server is not participating in an NT Domain, for user name instead of domain specify the `server_netbios_name\username`